# How do I fix an 'Undefined array key' warning in a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, php-8

I have just upgraded to php8 and my error log has a lot of warnings about an undefined array key in code that sets up a custom post type.

A snippet from this CPT code is:

```
function create_custom( $cpt = array() ) {
register_post_type($cpt['post_type'], array(
    'label'                     => __($cpt['label'], 'kbo'),
    'description'               => __($cpt['description'], 'kbo'),
    'public'                    => true,
    'show_ui'                   => true,
    'show_in_menu'              => $cpt['show_in_menu'],
    'capability_type'           => 'post',
```

The line causing the warning is 'show_in_menu'

How can I define this so that the warning stops?

Comment: `show_in_menu` key doesn't exist in `$cpt` that's what the error is saying. what you have in `$cpt`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check $cpt array, but print_r($cpt) if $cpt array dont have show_in_menu then you can directly place true or false depending on your output.